# Checking pixel value of large image (Pointer Offset to large for 64bit?)

Tags: image, pointers, opencv, processing, offset

I seem to be having an issue with a pointer offset when converting a large grayscale image to color.  I'm converting a 24,000 x 27,000 grayscale image to a 32bit RGB image for Direct2D (requirement for D2D).

I'm doing highlighting to the image and haven't really found a way to do it automatically with a custom palette so I've just looped through all pixel values and manually set them on the 32bit image.  It works just fine on smaller images but crashes when trying to use a larger image as I've described above.

Below is a code snippet.

```
    CvMat* dst = cvCreateMat(height, width, CV_8UC4);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(nThreads)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for( int Y = 0; Y < height; Y++ )
        {
            for( int X = 0; X < width; X++ ) 
            {
                size_t nOffset = X + Y * width;
                size_t nOffsetRGB = (X  +  Y * width) * 4;

                switch( pPixelData[nOffset] )
                {
                    case 0: //red
                    {
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB] = 0;
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB + 1] = 0;
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB + 2] = 255;
                        //pDestination[nOffsetRGB + 3] = 255; //alpha opacity %
                        break;
                    }
                    default: //GrayScale
                    {
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB] = pPixelData[nOffset];
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB + 1] = pPixelData[nOffset];
                        dst->data.ptr[nOffsetRGB + 2] = pPixelData[nOffset];
                        //pDestination[nOffsetRGB + 3] = 255; //pSource[nOffset]; //alpha %
                        break;
                    }
                }

            } //next X
        } //next Y
    }
```

This code will eventually crash with an error about accessing memory, which I wouldn't think is possible since I've checked the grayscale image is good and have plenty of memory (16gb).  It also works just fine on slightly smaller images.

Any idea's what I could be doing wrong here, this is my first time converting a program over to 64bit so I could be missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: You should use C++ API. I also don't understand why you do not use cvtColor() method. Spare yourself the trouble.

Comment: does the cvtColor method allow me to assign custom pixel values?  I threshold my grayscale image so I can use a few values for my own highlighting, say 0-5.  I have also tried using the C++ library of OpenCV and it seems to have the same behaviour, no error is produced it just exits the function (OpenCV 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do not account for gaps in the data that may occur due to aligning. It is called stepping. You can read a ton of useful information about it here:

[Mat::isContinuous()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=stepping#bool%20Mat%3a%3aisContinuous%28%29%20const)

I don't know if this is  the source of your error or not, but accessing matrix elements by pointers is often error-prone, so it is advisable to avoid it.

The OpenCV C++ API provides several nice, and efficient ways of safe data access. In your case, the most clean and easy to read method is to use iterators. For this, you use an explicitely typed matrix. Example code follows.

```
cv::Mat1b src = …
cv::Mat4b dest(src.rows, src.cols);
cv::Mat1b::const_iterator its = src.begin();
cv::Mat4b::iterator itd = dest.begin();
for (; its != src.end(); ++its, ++itd)
{
    uchar s = *its;
    cv::Vec4b &d = *itd;
    d[0] = s; d[1] = s; d[2] = s;
}
```

**Note:** You need a recent OpenCV version for this to work.

### OpenCV 2.1 is very buggy. Do not use anything less than 2.3.

Comment: Interesting, now I also use IPP, if I use some of the functions it provides how will/would it handle the data not being continuous?  I will work on updating to the current version of OpenCV asap.

Comment: IPP also works with step, it is called stride there. It is the second parameter to the IPP functions, after the data pointer parameter. Btw. most OpenCV code works with SSE instructions now, so the speed advantage of IPP is not as relevant today as it was a couple of years ago.